# Error occured when getting the data file through URL using python

Tags: python, pandas, dns, python-requests, urllib

I tried to load data from a URL

```
url = 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv'
chipo = pd.read_csv(url, sep = '\t')
```

and there is an error

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I've checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220091/two-errors-fetching-data-from-the-web-with-pandas-incompleteread-urlopen-erro) but this does not help.

I've also tried fetching data using `requests` and the error occured again

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000029B29E43748>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

It seems that there is something wrong with DNS so I edited the hosts file but it does not help either. How should I fix this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This problem shouldn't be reproducible lol. It turns out that there is something wrong with the DNS. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case solved. It turns out to be the problem of the DNS and I need the proxy to get access to the resources. This could explain why this problem is not reproducible.

```
import socket
import socks
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 10808)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/chipotle.tsv'
chipo = pd.read_csv(url, sep = '\t')
```